# Ebean ManyToMany to same entity

Tags: many-to-many, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to map a many to many releationship where every user has a set of friends, which also are users. In the database table this is solved using a assosiation table called user_friend. The user_friend table has two columns for user1 and user2 that is foreign keys to the user id in the user table.

The optimal solution would be to not create a java ebean model for the user_friend table, but let the user model have a set of users, where the current user is either user1 or user2 in the user_friend table. The mapping would then have to refer to the two columns in the user_friend table somehow...

Is this possible?

Edited: SQL for 1.sql added

```
CREATE TABLE User (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
email varchar2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
name varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE User_friend (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user1 bigint(20) NOT NULL,
user2 bigint(20) NOT NULL,
sent TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
accepted TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY(user1) REFERENCES User(id),
FOREIGN KEY(user2) REFERENCES User(id)
);
```

The thing is, want every user instance to have a set of users that he is linked to by being either user1 or user2.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is exactly how Ebean has set it up for you:

```
user_friend
   user1      user2
   (user_id)  (user_id)
```

Why do you want to change the ManyToMany relationship?  Could you provide us with the relevant piece of your 1.sql file in 'conf/evolutions/default'?

Update:

If your Java code looks like this:

```
@ManyToMany
public Set<User> friends = new HashSet<User>();
```

You should be able to get a set of friends by referencing user.friends.

The issue is it looks like you want to have additional fields in the User_friend table (sent, accepted).  Because of this you need to create a new model, UserFriend, that exposes these fields.

Comment: Well, I do not want expose those fields, they're really just there for logging. I think I will have to rethink my datastructure maybe..thanks for the help though!